# Scrollbar not stretching to fit the Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, scrollbar

I was able to get the `Scrollbar` to work with a `Text` widget, but for some reason it isn't stretching to fit the text box.

Does anyone know of any way to change the height of the scrollbar widget or something to that effect?

```
txt = Text(frame, height=15, width=55)
scr = Scrollbar(frame)
scr.config(command=txt.yview)
txt.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
txt.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your question you're using `pack`. `pack` has options to tell it to grow or shrink in either or both the x and y axis. Vertical scrollbars should normally grow/shrink in the y axis, and horizontal ones in the x axis. Text widgets should usually fill in both directions.

For doing a text widget and scrollbar in a frame you would typically do something like this:

```
scr.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

The above says the following things:

- scrollbar is on the right (`side="right"`)
- scrollbar should stretch to fill any extra space in the y axis (`fill="y"`)
- the text widget is on the left (`side="left"`)
- the text widget should stretch to fill any extra space in the x and y axis (`fill="both"`)
- the text widget will expand to take up all remaining space in the containing frame (`expand=True`)

For more information see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.grid()
scrl = Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrl.set)
scrl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
root.mainloop()
```

this makes a text box and the `sticky='ns'` makes the scrollbar go all the way up and down the window

Comment: your example neglects to set a weight to the row or column, so it probably won't resize properly.

Comment: Found your answer useful. This worked for me   sticky='ns'.

Answer (score 4):

Easy solution to use a textbox with an integrated scrollbar:

**Python 3**:

```
#Python 3
import tkinter 
import tkinter.scrolledtext

tk = tkinter.Tk() 
text = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(tk)
text.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

To read the textbox:

```
string = text.get("1.0","end")   # reads from the beginning to the end
```

Of course you can shorten the imports if you want.

In **Python 2** you `import ScrolledText` instead.

Comment: In Python 2 this is:

    `from ScrolledText import ScrolledText`
    `...`
    `text = ScrolledTex(tk)`

.